# How to run a Lua script within a Windows Forms TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lua

I used Visual Studio 2019 to build a form of some sort that I want to use to execute scripts in a `TextBox` within that textbox, so if I do `print("Hello");` the next line will be hello.
I use `FastColoredTextBox` to do that and I noticed it has a language property that I already set to Lua. How can I actually execute commands within that textbox tho?

I appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [`DynamicLua`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicLua/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) package to compile and run Lua code in C#.

For example, I assume you have a `fastColoredTextBox1` on your form and a button to `toolStripButton1` to run the code, then you can add the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.fastColoredTextBox1.Language = FastColoredTextBoxNS.Language.Lua;
    this.fastColoredTextBox1.Text= "function echo(s) return s end" + "\n" +
        "return echo(\"Hello!\")";
}

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic lua = new DynamicLua.DynamicLua();
    var result = lua(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show($"{result}"); 
}
```

[image]